# Color overlay on shape

Tags: html, css, colors, overlay, shapes

I've got a small problem.

I want to create an overlay effect on the picture in the following jsfiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/39gud4bh/1/

```
<div>
<img id="bubble" src="http://png-1.findicons.com/files/icons/2711/free_icons_for_windows8_metro/128/speech_bubble.png">
<img src="http://s30.postimg.org/lptvfyod9/speech_bubbleorange.png">
</img>
</div>

#bubble {

}
```

I want the overlay to have the color #ff9f2d

How is this possible? Been trying litterally everything i could find. The problem is that the image (might not be in jsfiddle) is a shape with a transparent background. This causes all my attempts to background/foreground filter the color to recolor the whole square instead of just the shape.

Really need some help.
In advance - Thank you!

## EDIT - Fiddle has been updated to entail the desired outcome of the CSS on the grey bubble.

Comment: this is kind of unclear. Can you paste an image of what you expect the final output to look like? Also what CSS did you try? Your specifier is empty.

Comment: Fiddle has been updated, to desired outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the exact answer you're looking for, but maybe you can consider using Font Awesome. It'll be a clean, sharp bubble and you can easily resize and color it anyway you want with CSS. Another route would be to use [SVG](http://css-tricks.com/using-svg/).

http://jsfiddle.net/wilchow/39gud4bh/5/

```
.fa-bubble {
    font-size: 140px;
    color: #333333;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.fa-bubble:hover {
    color: #ff9f2d;
}
```

Comment: SVG would definitely be the optional solution here.

Comment: Thank you very much WIL.
Was not even aware of these kinda solutions, opened up my spectrum alot! Thank you, have a nice evening!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think  you can turn that yellow bubble into gray one with just css.

You could do that if you reversed transparent and colored parts, and filled whole square with color. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Arministrator/j5gLgyt8/

```
    #bubble_img{
      background:yellow;
}
    #bubble_img:hover{
          background:#ff9f2d;
```

Or you can use two images (css sprites even better) as shown in one of the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Just move the second image over the first and set opacity

```css
#overlay {z-index:100;opacity:0.2;position:relative;left:-131px;top:-3px;
    
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img id="bubble" src="http://png-1.findicons.com/files/icons/2711/free_icons_for_windows8_metro/128/speech_bubble.png">
    </img>
    <img id="overlay" src="http://s30.postimg.org/lptvfyod9/speech_bubbleorange.png">
</div>
```

Comment: First of all - Thank you for the answer.

Comment: BUT, this is not what I aimed for. I want to recolor the grey bubble to the same color as the orange bubble. 

But I want to create the effect in ONLY CSS.
Pretend as if the orange bubble wasn't there - It's ONLY there for the purpose of describing the problem.

Comment: #Billy, because I won't be able to use two pictures.
And i need to make the orange color a :hover effect on the original WHITE bubble.

Comment: you don't need to if you only want the orange one ? bit confused at what you're trying to do. do you want it to change color on hover or something ? ps. my answer is only CSS

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no CSS property that will allow you change a gray colored image into a colored one.

However, the reverse is possible using CSS filters.

So if we reverse the 'process' and make the colored image appear grey by default we can remove that styling, perhaps on hover, to achieve the effect we are looking for.

```css
#bubble {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(1) brightness(0.3);
}
#bubble:hover {
  -webkit-filter: none
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img id="bubble" src="http://s30.postimg.org/lptvfyod9/speech_bubbleorange.png" />
</div>
```

[**Jsfiddle Comparison**](http://jsfiddle.net/39gud4bh/6/)

**NOTE**: CSS filters are **highly** experimental and browser support is poor.

> **This is an experimental technolog**y
>
> Because this technology's
>   specification has not stabilized, check the compatibility table for
>   the proper prefixes to use in various browsers. Also note that the
>   syntax and behavior of an experimental technology is subject to change
>   in future versions of browsers as the spec changes

[**MDN Reference**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter)

[**CanIUse.com Reference**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters)